# PHP change string before insert to database

Tags: php, html

I need to insert a method of how to do something into a database field. However i need to store this as a string with the html tags. For example the below list would be:

```
<ul>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

- List item
- List item
- List item

How would i store that list in the database with the aforementioned html tags field so that it can be used later and printed out again in html as a list?

thanks

Comment: html's just plain text. Insert the html snippet as you would any other string data.

Comment: How does PHP change your input/string?

Comment: Friendly advice, don't store the html tags in your database. Style the results after you pull the data out.

Comment: what's wrong with simply storing that as a string? ie. in a 'text' column type in MySQL

Comment: If it is user-input, don't forget to filter the data to avoid XSS or SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way you are storing any other data.

Answer (score -2):

in PHP you can use

```
addslashes(string)
```

This will escape the html and as long as you store it in a subtible column in the DB you are fine

Comment: I think the OP wants to print out the HTML _as_ HTML, instead of text, when they retrieve it. While your answer is correct for escaping HTML, unfortunately it doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: NO, addslashes does not escape HTML, but single quote, double quote, null and blackslash.

Comment: No, actually his answer is incorrect for escaping HTML. `addslashes` doesn't escape HTML and shouldn't be used to escape strings that are to be used in a query.